# google plugin installation in eclipse

Tags: plugins, bundle

i am trying to install google plugin in eclipse. maybe that does have some prehistoric issues with me or my pc. problems are overflowing, they keep on coming . i've pasted the code for the problem i've currently encountered .-

-`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)   Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plu`

what should i do this time ?